# Interface stored in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

So I ran across this code online:

```
public static interface Node 
{
    int getValue();
    List<Node> getChildren();
}
```

Can someone explain `List<Node> getChildren()`? I don't really understand this because the interface is called Node, so is this an arraylist of interfaces?

This code is a snippet of several sample methods that manipulate trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getChildren()` method of any class that implements the `Node` interface must return a `List<Node>`, which is a list whose elements can be any object whose class implements the  `Node` interface.

It could, of course, be an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, or any other class that implements `List`.  But the thing that makes it a `List<Node>` is that you can add any object to it whose class implements `Node`, and when you get an object from it, the class of that object is guaranteed to be an implementation of `Node`.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. The only thing that I don't really understand is if I had a class that implemented this interface, how would I make a list of strings (for example) be stored List<Node> so that I can return it?

Comment: You'd need a way of converting a `String` to an object of some class that implements `Node`.  Not quite sure how you'd do this, since in your example, a `Node` seems to wrap an integer.

Comment: Your first sentence is the answer/clarification I was looking for. Thanks for your help, this makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Node> getChildren()` returns all the children of a specific node. This list will have the Objects that are of Node type i.e objects of classes that implements Node.